# Mac OS X server - cannot add devices to MDM server

Tags: mac, usb, pfsense

Mac OS X 10.14.4 - Server 5.8

I am trying to add devices to the server to manage them, the server is set up, the certificates as well, the Trust profile and the enrollment profiles are set, but when i try to Enroll a device - either macOS or iOS, I get errors about the device not able to communicate with the server.

on iOS:
First error: **Profile Failed to Install**
Second error, if I retry: **the SCEP server returned an invalid response**

for Mac OS
**Error: Profile installation failed. An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server could not be made**
Funnily enough for those devices, they actually appear in the list of devices on the profile manager with the serial number but they have a "forbidden" sign on the side and cannot apply any policy to them.

---

Note: I run a network with multiple VLANs managed by a pfsense firewall array and tried to monitor the traffic but couldn't see any dropped packages, although I'm not very experienced with it.

---

my main original issue is to disable the ability for people from writing to USB devices ports on a set of MAC computers I have in my network

I already tried to do this via disabling the extensions but this is not working
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30347908/mac-os-x-10-10-yosemite-disable-usb-ports

p.s. I also saw Disk Arbitrator but wouldn't be sauitable
https://github.com/aburgh/Disk-Arbitrator

---

Advices, tips, anything is welcome as i'm getting quite impatient with this. Thanks!

Comment: What MDM service? Have you made sure you're following the proper steps for that MDM service?

Comment: I am using the embedded MDM service in mac os X server.
A colleague of mine managed to add a device leas year for testing, but when doing it together a couple of weeks ago we couldn't replicate, he left, and since then I've been trying unsuccessfully.
any guide that I read doesn't really help much as they go through the setup steps, but not really into the troubleshooting
https://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-add-devices-to-profile-manager-in-os-x-server/